# Do we need to resubmit a crowdloan, if we don't win the slot?

Tags: polkadot, kusama

I have opened a crowdloan to get enough funds to win a parachain slot on Kusama. I just want to know what to do if I don't get enough funds and I don't win the slot:

1. Do I need to resubmit the crowdloan?
2. Or will it be automatically resubmitted and keep running for the next auction until my chain becomes parachain?
3. If we don't win the slot and the crowdloan gets canceled, what happens to the funds (both those that Kusama reserved for the crowdloan submission, and funds that were contributed by community members)?
4. Can we start a new campaign along with existing one? or we have to wait for the current one to get finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, if you fail to win a slot with your crowdloan after it expires, you will need to start a new campaign. Each crowdloan has a expiration date, so that is when your crowdloan will end.
2. As long as your crowdloan has not expired, it can keep trying to bid into valid auctions, but as mentioned, once it expires, then you must start a new one.
3. All funds are returned to the users.
4. You must wait for the existing one to end before you can start a new crowdloan.